# Is termcap on cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to build something that apparently depends on termcap (it keeps saying `cannot find - ltermcap`).

I ran Cygwin's setup-x86_64.exe, hoping to install termcap from there; however, I did not find it in the package list, nor on the package list at the Cygwin website, so it seems like it isn't in Cygwin.  I can't accept that it isn't, because googling hints otherwise.

I could get termcap from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/termcap.htm, but I don't know if that is compatible with Cygwin, and it seems much cleaner to use Cygwin.

Excuse me if I sound like I don't know what I'm talking about  because I probably don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### I ran Cygwin's setup-x86_64.exe, hoping to install termcap

> However, I did not find it in the package list

Note: From http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/termcap.htm:

> However, use of termcap is discouraged. Termcap is being phased out in favor of the terminfo-based ncurses library, which contains an emulation of the termcap library routines in addition to an excellent curses implementation.

So, on Cygwin you should build using `ncurses` instead.

- You may need to tweak the `makefile` for the program you are trying to build in order to do this (so that it links with the correct libraries for the `ncurses` emulation of `termcap`)
- The Cygwin `ncurses` package includes:

  ```
  usr/include/ncurses/termcap.h -> ../termcap.h
  ```

  Which provides an interface to the `ncurses` emulation of `termcap`

You can always find out what packages contain particular cygwin commands using [Search Packages](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi):

[image]

I would suggest installing:

- [cygwin32-ncurses-5.7-1](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fcygwin32-ncurses%2Fcygwin32-ncurses-5.7-1&grep=termcap) - cygwin32-ncurses: ncurses for Cygwin 32bit toolchain (installed binaries and support files)
- [libncurses-devel-6.0-1.20151017](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Flibncurses-devel%2Flibncurses-devel-6.0-1.20151017&grep=termcap) - libncurses-devel: Terminal display library (installed binaries and support files)

Answer (score 5):

Cygwin uses [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html), which provides a termcap *interface*.  It has done this for some time (see [notes from 2001](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2001/msg00124.html)).  ncurses provides [interfaces](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#uses_of_library) for termcap, terminfo and of course curses.

On some systems, the ncurses package may provide a symbolic link to help applications that expect the library providing the termcap interface to be named "termcap", e.g.,.

```
libtermcap.a -> libncurses.a
```

but (see [runtime](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Flibncursesw10%2Flibncursesw10-6.0-1.20151017&grep=ncurses) and [development](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Flibncurses-devel%2Flibncurses-devel-6.0-1.20151017&grep=ncurses) lists), Cygwin does not do this.  Nor (as you note) does it provide a separate termcap library (see [search results](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=termcap&arch=x86_64)).